# How do i do this in a simple way?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, dictionary

If i have 3 columns in a `DataTable` with following data:

```
1 A qwqw
2 A wewe
3 B tyty
4 B trtr
5 C iuiu
```

What is the easiest and efficient way in which i can put the above data into a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Foo))` like this:

```
[A] -> {New Foo(1, A, qwqw), New Foo(2, A, wewe)}
[B] -> {New Foo(3, B, tyty), New Foo(4, B, trtr)}
[C] -> {New Foo(5, C, iuiu)}
```

where `Foo` is a type with members that represent the fields in the table.
What i have done is written a query(LINQ) to first get the unique values in the 2nd columns in a `List(Of String)`. Then iterated over this list to fire another query for each element in the list to get the corresponding rows in a list out of which objects of Foo are created and put in a list which is then added to my `Dictionary` as value with the key as the element. Any ideas?

Comment: I can give you a C# answer if you can translate it to vb.net.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. If i am successful, i will post the result back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a C# answer:

```
myDataTable.Rows.GroupBy(r => r[1]).ToDictionary(
    g => g.Key
,   g => g.Select(rr => new Foo(rr[0], rr[1], rr[2])).ToList()
);
```

The idea is to first group by the middle column (#1), and then convert groups to dictionary, using group key as the dictionary key, and creating `Foo` from each row in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to dasblinkenlight, i managed to convert his C# construct to VB.NET:

```
Dim r as Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
r = myDataTable.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(Function(x) x(1).ToString()).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Select(Function(rr) New Foo(rr.Field(Of String)(0), rr.Field(Of String)(1), rr.Field(Of String)(2)).ToList())
```

And it works perfect.

Comment: ok, I like the way you put effort in the answer given by dasblinkenlight and provide the answer in your application language. Thus upvote for you and dasblinkenlight, something refreshing.